Gapless audio for RTMP stream loop
A repost from SO since I guess people didn't like it there..
I'm trying to make a looped RTMP stream from a single video (in this
example - YouTube), but starting with version 6.0 it introduces a gap in-between loops in the audio which is quite audible. Version before 6.0 (I
tried 5.1.6 and 4.4.2) work as expected and don't introduce any gaps.
The difference I spotted is that the master version (7.0.2) and the 5.1.6, for
example, report a different duration time. Is there any reason why that might happen?
v5.1.6:
 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'demo-video.mp4':
   Metadata:
     major_brand     : isom
     minor_version   : 512
     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
     creation_time   : 2024-09-03T15:30:51.000000Z
     encoder         : Blackmagic Design DaVinci Resolve Studio
   Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 35440 kb/s

v7.0.2:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'demo-video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2024-09-03T15:30:51.000000Z
    encoder         : Blackmagic Design DaVinci Resolve Studio
  Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 35346 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 35240 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2024-09-03T15:30:51.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : H.264 NVIDIA
        timecode        : 01:00:00:00

As you can see, v5.1.6 report duration of 00:00:05.00 (which is correct) and v7.0.2 is 00:00:05.01 (1ms longer), which is what I think is causing the issue (but I'm not so sure about that). The original file is 5 seconds long which is what can be checked by ffprobe as well, but some streams report a 00:05.01 duration time.
I tried to remedy this issue in many different ways by trimming the video/audio, using different flags, like -shortest, but that didn't help in any way - there's still a gap in the audio which is noticeable when looping the video. And like I said versions such as v5.1.6 work fine and there's no such gap.
I guess what changed between versions is how ffmpeg interprets these streams but in the end I spent 2 days trying to avoid gaps in audio when streaming and nothing helped.
How to reproduce:
You can just stream the video in any RTMP destination of your liking, like YouTube and observe that there would be gaps (audio break-ups) in between every 5 seconds (once video ends). Video is accessible through the link from the curl command
curl -o stream-audio-gap-issue.mp4 https://r2v.streamloop.app/obj_01j6y0pk83fy8vp06a9mmkkqah.mp4
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i stream-audio-gap-issue.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/[your-key]

Expected: there are no gaps every 5 seconds, like in old versions of ffmpeg
Instead: there are tiny audio gaps which are quite noticable
ffprobe outputs is available on gist: https://gist.github.com/blitss/1e221b4fa8885b1df8ac2096746239cf
I'm looking for literally any workarounds that will help avoid audio gaps whilst still preserving the latest version of ffmpeg.
